# C2061 'string': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, string, identifier

I am getting a 'string': undeclared identifier error when trying to build a solution to my program. 
I believe it has something to do with declaring a string type in a function declaration. The error first appears in the function signature for add node:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

void addNode(struct Node *head, string text);

struct Node {
    string info;
    string out;
    Node* next;
};
```

here is the rest of the code for the program:

```
int main()
{
    const int width = 2; // the number of cells on the X axis
    const int height = 2; // the number of cells on the Y axis
    string grid[height];

    struct Node *list = new Node;
    struct Node *listcpy;

    grid[0] = "00";
    grid[0] = "0.";

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        addNode(list, grid[i]);
    }

    listcpy = list; //holds pointer to beggining of list

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (list->info[j] == '0') //if current cell is a node
            {
                list->out.append(to_string(i) + " " + to_string(j) + " "); //append nodes coordinate

                if (j < width - 1) //if right cell exists
                {
                    if (list->info[j + 1] == '0') { //if there is node to the right
                        list->out.append(to_string(i) + " " + to_string(j + 1) + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        list->out.append("-1 -1 ");
                    }

                    if (i < height - 1) //if bottom cell exists
                    {
                        if (list->next->info[j] == '0') { //if there is node at the bottom
                            list->out.append(to_string(i + 1) + " " + to_string(j) + " ");
                        }
                        else {
                            list->out.append("-1 -1 ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                list = list->next;
            }

            while (listcpy != NULL)
            {
                if (listcpy->out != "")
                {
                    cout << listcpy->out << endl;
                }
                listcpy = listcpy->next;
            }


        }
    }
}

// apending
void addNode(struct Node *head, string text)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->info = text;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->out = "";

    Node *cur = head;
    while (cur) {
        if (cur->next == NULL) {
            cur->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to correct this error?

Comment: Get rid of `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: `struct Node *list` <- `struct` is not required in C++ as a `struct` declaration declares a new type name.

Comment: If you are working in Visual Studio and have precompiled headers on, `#include "stdafx.h"` *must* be the first include.

Comment: Is that the first error message? Your problem might be that your `addNode` declaration precedes the `struct Node` definition, so the compiler doesn't know what the first parameter type for the function is. You can fix that by moving the `addNode` declaration after `struct Node`. And get rid of precompiled headers and `#include "stdafx.h"` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have precompiled headers mode enabled:

[image: Project -> Settings -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers -> Precompiled Header: Use (/Yu)]

In this case everything that comes before the `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored. Like it or not, this is how Microsoft implemented the precompiled header feature.

Therefore, you either need to disable precompiled headers for your project and remove `#include "stdafx.h"`, or you need to make sure that `#include "stdafx.h"` is always the first line (except for comments, but in any case they do not play any role) at the top of every code file. (This does not apply to headers.)